# High write latency on tempdb datafiles only

Tags: sql-server, performance, tempdb

I'm experiencing large write latency on our tempdb database, but on no other database.
(from sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats) Tempdb log file latency is also listed as being below 5ms.

For comparison:
Write latency on all databases except tempdb are below 5ms, tempdb was about 500ms when using 8 datafiles. I removed 4 datafiles 2 days ago just to check if something changes and it looks like the latency doubled after doing this.

A few notes on our environment:

- SQL Server 2008 R2 SP3 VM running on Hyper-V
- one large RAID10 array attached to our Hyper-V hosts via fibre channel where everything is stored

I have no explanation for this and I don't know where to look for answers.
I could of course assume that doubling the data files will half the WriteLatency but I don't know if this is the way to go.

Any ideas on where to start?

Comment: Can you see with [sp_whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com/) the process using the tempdb?

Comment: In order to better observe the behavior of tempdb specifically, I'd suggest putting Extended Events to work. Great post on monitoring tempdb from William Durkin: https://williamdurkin.com/2015/09/who-blew-up-my-tempdb/

Comment: Also, look at Jes Borlands script on object creation in tempdb: https://github.com/grrlgeek/extended-events

Comment: @GrantFritchey Thanks for the useful links. The first one only reacts on database growth I believe which I disabled for tempdb-data-files and presized them. I will have a look a those scripts and see if they will also work with 2008 R2, the README says they are for SQL Server 2012+.

Thanks so far, I will report back if I find something.

Answer (score 3):

I seem to have solved it or at least know where it is coming from.

To find out I setup perfmon to monitor avg. ms per write operation and it looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgHFA.jpg). which leads me to the conclusion that those extreme spikes only happen during nightly index rebuilding (I'm using Ola Hallengrens IndexMaintenance-solution for this), normal operation is fine.

My learning: don't rely on cumulated stats in sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats only, but they are a good indicator to look further for the origin.

Comment: Great solution. Well done.